# Butt Generator?

Tags: modeling, mesh, add-on

I've recently learned of a few addons such as MakeHuman and ManualBastioniLab for making ready human characters. I was wondering if there's something like that for individual body parts, like the butt.

I'm not interested in modeling at all, as animation is mainly my thing, however, I dip into Blender on occasion to edit models that I use.

What I'm currently trying to do is edit a model to give them a butt.

Here's a reference photo for what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

And here's what I have so far in Blender:

[image]

As you can see, I've got some work to do. If anyone knows an add-on that can help make things easier, or if you're good with butts and can help guide me, I'd love if we could chat on Discord for a screenshare or if you could help me in general. My discord name is Sonario648#7356 and Im also in the Blender discord server.

Comment: Jesus Christ! There is no such thing that I know of. How about learning the basics and model it yourself? Tons of tuts out there...

Comment: @metaphor_set jesus christ was my initial reaction as well, hahahahaha